# robolectric java.lang.AssertionError while unit testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I have a login form which contains two edit texts, one to enter an emailId and another to enter a password. I have written a simple method to validate that these fields are not empty. This is my method

```
public boolean validate() {

    if(edtEmail.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        showErrorMessage(true);
        return false;
    }

    if(edtPassword.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        showErrorMessage(false);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have written a unit test for this method

```
@Test
public void check_validate() {
    EditText edtEmail = loginActivity.findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
    EditText edtPassword=loginActivity.findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
    assertTrue(loginActivity.validate());
}
```

I am getting the error as **java.lang.AssertionError**. All i want to check is whether the function is working correctly.

Comment: Is that AssertionError thrown by the `assertTrue` method? If so, that means that either `edtEmail` or `edtPassword` or both are non-empty.

Comment: @MCEmperor yes, the error is thrown by assertTrue method. I am not getting what do you by they are non-empty. if they are non-empty the validate function should return true, and so the assertTrue method should also be true and the test should not have failed. Correct me if I am wrong I am new to testing and I am little jumbled up.

Comment: edtEmail.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(null) . add this one alos

Comment: @srb1991 My bad. I mean, of course, "empty" instead of "non-empty". Both have to be non-empty for the test to pass. That is not the case, hence both are empty. Can we see the definition of `edtEmail` and `edtPassword`?

Comment: @swaroop i replaced the line and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @MCEmperor